# ORACLE join two queries into one

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to join two queries where the only difference is on the clause `RECIP like '44%' ==> RECIP not like '44%'` and have unique output

```
   select FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3-PART, sum(c) from
   ( select FIELD1, FIELD2, SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2) as FIELD3-PART, count(*) as c from
    table
   where timestamp between sysdate - interval '120' minute and sysdate - interval '2' minute 
   FIELD3 is not null and FIELD3 like '44%'
   group by FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)
   group by FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3-PART
   HAVING ((sum(c) > '150' and SUBSTR(ORIG, 1,6)='333441')  
   or (sum(c) > '100' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,6)='333442')      
   or (sum(c) > '250' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,6)='333443')
   or (sum(c) > '10' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,6)='333444'));
   
   select FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3-PART, sum(c) from
   ( select FIELD1, FIELD2, SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2) as FIELD3-PART, count(*) as c from
    table
   where timestamp between sysdate - interval '120' minute and sysdate - interval '2' minute 
   FIELD3 is not null and FIELD3 not like '44%'
   group by FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)
   group by FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3-PART
   HAVING ((sum(c) > '150' and SUBSTR(ORIG, 1,6)='333441')  
   or (sum(c) > '100' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,6)='333442')      
   or (sum(c) > '250' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,6)='333443')
   or (sum(c) > '10' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,6)='333444'));
```

I know there is for sure more "elegant" way to do the queries and have the output I need, but I'm not sql expert, and actually the two queries work perfect.
Thank you
Lucas

Comment: Can you use UNION?

Comment: Yes, I can, but basically with union I'll have two query. Because I have the same fields and only one different clause, the quesy can be adjusted into one

Answer (score 0):

You can update your query to -

```
select FIELD1,
       FIELD2,
       FIELD3-PART,
       sum(c)
  from (select FIELD1,
               FIELD2,
               SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2) as FIELD3-PART,
               count(*) as c
          from table
         where timestamp between sysdate - interval '120' minute and sysdate - interval '2' minute 
           -- AND FIELD3 is not null        -- No need to use this line as LIKE predicate automatically filters null values.
           and FIELD3 like '44%'
         group by FIELD1, FIELD2, SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2))
 group by FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3-PART
HAVING sum(c) > '50' 
   and SUBSTR(ORIG, 1,6) IN ('333441', '333442', '333443', '333444');
```

I still have a doubt that your query will work since there is nothing called ORIG (used in the HAVING clause), I can see in your query.

Comment: Yes, my typo, ORIG is FIELD2. Let me try your solution, and for now thanks. 

EDIT: Please note, the HAVING COUNTS is always different, I believe your code is not fit my needs. I'll try to adjust it, thank you

Comment: EDIT AGAIN: Your query will only take care of FIELD3 like '44%', I'm I wrong? I need both FIELD3 like '44%' and FIELD3 not like '44%'

Comment: After those 2 edits., I think your query is perfect.

Comment: I don't thinks so, your query seems only take care of like '44%' on clause, so it's not ok for me since I need both like and not like

Comment: I meant to say after your 2 above suggested edits the queries you are using were perfectly fine. Please discard my query and keep using your queries.